# Drupal Website Scraping

Tags: php, angularjs, drupal, web-scraping, phantomjs

What is the best option in Scraping the content of the website?
The website is in Drupal7 and PHP 5.5.9.
I want to scrape after web page fully loaded.

I know there are some options like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and others but I'm unable to get content after full page load with PhantomJS.

My script for PhantomJS is this:

```
var page = new WebPage()

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  console.log(page.content);
  phantom.exit();
};

page.open("https://www.mywebsite.com/", function() {

});
```

Any other option or someone having a script for PhantomJS to scrape page after fully loaded.

Comment: There are several ways to scrape a website. You can do it on a command line or use already made tools to do so. https://github.com/ContentMine/quickscrape

Comment: Thanks for the answer but quickscrape is not possible with Dot Net Framework.